# What is the usual way to install a gem in ruby under RVM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm

I'm new on Ruby on Rails.

Now I want to use rvm; in this article
http://www.skorks.com/2010/01/using-multiple-rubies-seamlessly-on-the-one-machine-with-rvm/

it introduces:

```
sudo gem install rvm
```

to allow for a different ruby version. What confused me is gem is a package installer for ruby. Does it require the ruby language preinstalled? Do I need to have a ruby version installed first?

What's the usual way to install gem in RVM?

Comment: the installation via gem is no more supported - but it was an option earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you don't need ruby installed to install rvm, just follow the instructions at http://rvm.io/rvm/install/

Comment: also i want to know the relation betwwen gem and ruby?